# What's a good metric to analyze the quality of the output of a clustering algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis, k-means, metric

I've been trying out the kmeans clustering algorithm implementation in scipy. Are there any standard, well-defined metrics that could be used to measure the quality of the clusters generated?

ie, I have the expected labels for the data points that are clustered by kmeans. Now, once I get the clusters that have been generated, how do I evaluate the quality of these clusters with respect to the expected labels?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

Comment: Thanks Mitch. I'm trying out the different measures listed over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I am doing this very thing at that time with Spark's KMeans.</sub>

I am using:

- The sum of squared distances of points to their nearest center
  (implemented in [computeCost()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=kmeans#pyspark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel.computeCost)).
- The Unbalanced factor (see
  [Unbalanced factor of KMeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235576/unbalanced-factor-of-kmeans)
  for an implementation and
  [Understanding the quality of the KMeans algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240078/understanding-the-quality-of-the-kmeans-algorithm)
  for an explanation).

Both quantities promise a better cluster, when the are small (the less, the better).

Answer (score 0):

Kmeans attempts to minimise a sum of squared distances to cluster centers. I would compare the result of this with the Kmeans clusters with the result of this using the clusters you get if you sort by expected labels.

There are two possibilities for the result. If the KMeans sum of squares is larger than the expected label clustering then your kmeans implementation is buggy or did not get started from a good set of initial cluster assignments and you could think about increasing the number of random starts you using or debugging it. If the KMeans sum of squares is smaller than the expected label clustering sum of squares and the KMeans clusters are not very similar to the expected label clustering (that is, two points chosen at random from the expected label clustering are/are not usually in the same expected label clustering when they are/are not in the KMeans clustering) then sum of squares from cluster centers is not a good way of splitting your points up into clusters and you need to use a different distance function or look at different attributes or use a different sort of clustering.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, when you do have the samples true label, validation is very easy.
First of all, compute the confusion matrix (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix). Then, derive from it all relevant measures: True Positive, false negatives, false positives and true negatives. Then, you can find the Precision, Recall, Miss rate, etc.

Make sure you understand the meaning of all above. They basically tell you how well your clustering predicted / recognized the true nature of your data.

If you're using python, just use the sklearn package: 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

In addition, it's nice to run some internal validation, to see how well your clusters are separated. There are known internal validity measures, like:
Silhouette
DB index
Dunn index
Calinski-Harabasz measure
Gamma score
Normalized Cut
etc.

Read more here: An extensive comparative study of cluster validity indices
Olatz Arbelaitz , Ibai Gurrutxaga, , Javier Muguerza , Jesús M. Pérez , Iñigo Perona

Comment: Actually it is not that easy, because clusters != classes, so the confusion matrix doesn't allow you decide what is "true positive", because there is no one-on-one correspondence between clusters and classes.

Comment: Then, use the unsupervised measures (internal indices)

Comment: There are supervised indices, too. But they work differently than you explained...

Comment: The internal indices (Silhouette, DB index, Dunn index, etc.) doesn't require labeled data, hence they are not supervised.

Comment: Yes, but there *are* supervised indexes for clustering evaluation, too. Unsupervised indexes are usually biased towards k-means results, so k-means wins when comparing different algorithms...

Comment: Agree. What about measures like modularity or Ncut? They don't look at minimum distance from a center.

Comment: There are plenty. Like ARI. See the Wikipedia article.