# Unbalanced factor of KMeans?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, k-means, bigdata

Edit: The answer of this questions is heavily discussed in: [Sum in Spark gone bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627773/sum-in-spark-gone-bad)

---

In [Compute Cost of Kmeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216760/compute-cost-of-kmeans), we saw how one can compute the cost of his KMeans model. I was wondering if we are able to compute the Unbalanced factor?

If there is no such functionality provide by Spark, is there any easy way to implement this?

---

I was not able to find a ref for the Unbalanced factor, but it should be similar to Yael's unbalanced_factor (my comments):

```
// @hist: the number of points assigned to a cluster
// @n:    the number of clusters
double ivec_unbalanced_factor(const int *hist, long n) {
  int vw;
  double tot = 0, uf = 0;

  for (vw = 0 ; vw < n ; vw++) {
    tot += hist[vw];
    uf += hist[vw] * (double) hist[vw];
  }

  uf = uf * n / (tot * tot);

  return uf;

}
```

which I found [here](https://github.com/jackculpepper/yael/blob/master/yael/vector.c).

So the idea is that `tot` (for total) will be equal to the number of points assigned to clusters (i.e. equal to the size of our dataset), while `uf` (for unbalanced factor) holds the square of the number of points assigned to a cluster.

Finally he uses `uf = uf * n / (tot * tot);` to compute it.

Comment: Could you show a reference about what is the balance factor?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto it's how many points every centroid has, i.e. that after assigning the points of the dataset to the centroids (with `predict()` I guess), compute a factor that will indicate whether the data are balanced across centroids. Interestingly I cannot find a good ref, but you get the idea right? If I have 2 centroids, and 100 points are assigned to the 1st centroid,while 10 to the 2nd, then the balance factor should be bad. If the 1st has 60 points and the 2nd 50, then the balance factor should be could. So basically one would like to count the #points that are assigned everycentroid

Comment: But I found for unbalanced, @AlbertoBonsanto, updated!

Comment: Well if there isn't any implementation inside `Apache Spark`'s `KMeansModel` I think it is pretty easy to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `python` it could be something like:

```py
# I suppose you are passing an RDD of tuples, where the key is the cluster and the value is a vector with the features.
def unbalancedFactor(rdd):
  pdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b) # you can obtain the number of points per cluster
  n = pdd.count()
  total = pdd.map(lambda x: x[1]).sum() 
  uf = pdd.map(lambda x: x[1] * float(x[1])).sum()

  return uf * n / (total * total)
```

Comment: Works! So, the less the value of that factor (the minimum value is 1), the better (i.e. the clusters are ideally balanced). Do you agree?

Comment: For example, if I set all centroids to get assigned only 1 point, then `uf=1`. If I set half of the total points of the dataset to be assigned to one cluster, and all the other points to be assigned to different clusters, then `uf = 2`. If I assign a cluster one point, another cluster another point, and all the other points to another cluster, then `uf=2`...Hmm...I corrected some bugs in your code, as you should have seen by now! :)

Comment: I would say yes. However, in my experience Kmeans isn't so powerful/useful as you would expect, because it can't handle categorical variables, and when the number of dimensions increase, the conclusions you get aren't so clear. There are some other alternatives (I don't have them in my ming at this moment) which are pretty advanced, and I haven't worked with, but they seem promising.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my code, I didn't test it i just wrote it from my head.

Comment: In theory yes. But when tackling big data in high dimensions, even kmeans++ (another variation of kmeans, has a preeetty hard time), so I want to do some research on how far can kmeans go! After my last fix I got 1, 2.5 and 2.3. Of course Alberto I know, I just mentioned it so that we are on the same track (because I am trying to understand what the unbalanced factor can tell us)!!!! I thank you! :D It's a bit confusing that it's equal to 1 when every point is assigned to 1 cluster, and when every point is assigned to a different cluster.

Comment: I don't want to spam but this is what I tried to say [Cluster analysis](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/09/ClusterAnalysis_Mouse.svg/450px-ClusterAnalysis_Mouse.svg.png). In that picture you can see that there are 3 clusters, however Kmeans doesn't perform too good. Besides, Kmeans has a weird effect (I have seen it empirically) that it "tries" to create clusters of the same size. So, when the variance or the distance between the points of the same cluster is big, but you have another small cluster where all points are close the output of the algorithm is **weird**.

Comment: The function gives me the cribs: [Sum in Spark gone bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627773/sum-in-spark-gone-bad).